# Bind click event after deferred initialization of Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**How can I bind the click event after the deferred script is loaded?**

I have a Kendo Grid (in Razor) with deferred initialization due performance issues. So all js scripts are included in the end of the document.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City);
        columns
            .Bound(c => c.Id)
            .Title("Commands")
            .Sortable(false)
            .Filterable(false)
            .ClientTemplate(
                "<a href='" + @Url.Action("Details", new { id = "#=Id#" }) + 
                    "' class='btn btn-success' title='Details'>" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span></a>" +
                "<a href='" + @Url.Action("Edit", new { id = "#=Id#" }) +
                    "' class='btn btn-info' title='Edit'>" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>" +
                "<a href='\\#' data-id='#=Id#' data-action='deactivate' " +
                    "class='btn btn-warning' title='Desactivate'>" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></a>"
            );
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadData", "MyController")).Sort(a => a.Add("Name")))
    .Deferred()
)
```

Then I have a section at the end where I want to bind a click event to the `<a>` click of every element which a `data-action='deactivate'` attribute. The problem is the deffered initialization is performed after my document is ready.

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-action="deactivate"]').click(function (event) {
                var id = $(event.target).attr('data-id');
                alert(id);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using event delegation

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-action="deactivate"]'function (event) {
    var id = $(event.target).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

In this way, the target DOM element does not have to exist when the event is bound.

Comment: I would add to the answer the code `event.stopPropagation()` so the id is not undefined when propagating to the span element.